# Enviar datos usando POST a través de javascript sin usar un formulario

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, post

Quiero enviar unos datos almacenados en unas variables declaradas en un archivo, index.js de index.html a un backend que guarda los datos en Mongo DB. No quiero mandarlos a través de un formulario. ¿Cómo se puede hacer esto?

**Formato de respuesta válido**: Como la pregunta no pretende una respuesta exhaustiva que contemple todos los métodos posibles para hacer esto, se aceptará como respuesta válida, cualquiera que mencione al menos, una forma de hacer lo que se pide.

Comment: ¿has probado con ajax?  [En la red](https://www.google.com/search?q=ajax+post) encontrarás muchos ejemplos.

Comment: esto es literalmente un ejercicio de clase

Comment: @David Fernandez Flores: Efectivamente solo que yo soy el profesor y el...alumno.

Comment: @masterguru: Estoy intentándolo hacer con Fetch

Comment: `fetch( url, {method:"POST" ...`

Comment: Eso, continua revisando con `fetch`, por ahí vas bien encaminado, solo debes pasarle la URL a la que los quieres enviar y los datos que quieres mandar (asegurate de pasarlos en el formato correcto)

Comment: Para no andar escribiendo mucho prueba [este ejemplo de fetch](https://javascript.espaciolatino.com/ejemplos/apps/ofetch.htm), te puede servir como base. Los datos usan formato texto por simpllicidad, no te costará adaptarlo a JSON o cualquier formato que te interese.

Answer (score 1):

Podrías crear un objeto con los datos que guardaste en las variables declaradas, pasarlo a JSON y enviar esos datos por `fetch`.
Te quedaría algo así:

```
let datos = [ ... datos, {variable1: variable1, variable2: variable2, etc}];

let datosJSON = JSON.stringify(datos);

    fetch('URL a donde vas a enviar los datos',{
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            body: datosJSON
        });
```